# Stopping infinit loop from php script run in linux terminal

Tags: php, linux, terminal, exit

I am currently following a tutorial that teaches how to create a queue in php. An infinite loop was created in a php script. I simplified the code in order to focus on the question at hand:

```
while(1) {
        echo 'no jobs to do - waiting...', PHP_EOL;
        sleep(10);  
}
```

I use PuTTy (with an SSH connection) to connect to the linux terminal in my shared hosting account (godaddy). If I run `php queuefile.php`, I know it will run with no problems (already tested the code with a finite **for loop** instead of the infinite **while loop**).

**QUESTION:** How could I exit out of the infinite loop once it has started? I have already read online the option of creating code that **"checks"** if it should continue looping with something like the following code:

```
$bool = TRUE; 
while ($bool)
{
  if(!file_exists(allow.txt)){$bool = FALSE}
  //... the rest of the code
```

though I am curious if there might be a command I can type in the terminal, or a set of keys I can push that will cause the script to terminate. If there is any way of terminating the script, or if there is a better way to make the previous **"check"**, I would love your feedback!

Comment: I used to run a chat server using sockets on a linux machine.
You can use screen to host the application in a 'screen', if you want to quit, you could simply open up that screen and use control + c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should stop the running program that is running in the foreground.

You could also kill it when you login in another session an do some `ps aux | grep my-php-script.php` and see if it is your program, then you can use `pkill -f my-php-script.php` to kill this process.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! oh and you mentioned if I log in with another session. If I already had something working in a background, would killing it be done like you said: `pkill -f queuefile.php`? or does that only work If I called the php script in the same session?

Comment: @Webeng It will work in another session, you just need to be on the same machine and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I understand so that you want to make cron in your server. Therefore you should log in your server via putty and create cron job. 
For example: 
After logging...

```
crontab -e
```

Then add

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2
```